# Was the Dominion War created to help increase ratings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

I often wonder what DS9 would have been like without the Dominion War, and I was wondering if it was created to help increase ratings, much like the Xindi war was for Enterprise.

It seems that [Rick Berman and Majel Barrett didn't approve of the story line](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dominion_War#Background_information). Was it always the plan for DS9 to have the Dominion War?

Comment: *Everything* on a TV show is intended to improve ratings.

Comment: @Valorum - Damn that was fast! Do you just live on the star-trek tag (ha!)?. Was it like the Xindi War with Enterprise where they attempted to increase rating, or was that arc always planned?

Comment: I always thought it was to compete with Babylon 5's shadow war.

Comment: Also — "Was it always the plan for DS9 to have the Dominion War?" — I believe shows like Babylon 5, where a fairly detailed arc is somewhat-planned years ahead, are pretty rare. Ideas get discussed in writers rooms and meetings, but stuff usually isn't written until it's written. (Somewhat famously, [_The Best of Both Worlds Part 2_ wasn't planned until well after part 1 had aired](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds,_Part_II_(episode)#Story_and_script).) Why? [Because it's really hard to do!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad_%28season_2%29#Production).